# unable to reload the vite server we have to reload the html page manually

Tags: html, web, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yc5a.png)

no utility class were detected in the source file unable to vite is not abel to reload the webpage automatically we have to reload html page manually

Comment: for more clarification, you can send a mail-in mdatifraza926@gmail.com

Comment: can you provide the structure of your project and also `tailwind.config.js`, that would be helpful but  the error clearly telling you to check `content` in `tailwind.config.js` to include the path to the files